How to Integrate AWS-Based custom Data Platform with Power BI While maintaining RBAC and handling large Data Sizes?
We have an internally built and maintained Data Platform. Here is a brief summary of the problem:

The platform uses AWS services. We want users to create Power BI dashboards with data sourced from our data platform.
We have complete RBAC and user authentication for our users and want to maintain this consistency for Power BI dashboard creators.
The data can be large (in GBs) and we want the ability to refresh it regularly (if not in real-time).

We have explored various solutions, and the only viable one seems to be using Azure VNet Data Gateways. However, this requires a Premium Power BI license with a high number of Reserved Capacity Units, which is costly.
Does anyone have experience with this? Is there a simpler approach we might have missed? Any help and guidance would be appreciated.
Thank you!
Here are the things we have explored:

Streaming Database:

Limitations:

Supports only a few visualization types (line, bar, column charts, gauge).
Data transmission limitations: Power BI push datasets limitations.




Custom Data Connector:

Limitations:

Users must input or edit queries in Power BI Desktop each time.
Installing the data connector is cumbersome and not seamless.




Virtual Network Data Gateways:

Limitations:

Requires upgrading from Pro to Premium for licensing capacity. Price calculator.





Please correct us if any of this is inaccurate.
